# Making base map from image with known corner coordinates?

Tags: openlayers, mars

I'm trying to make a map in Openlayers using an image of a crater from mars (specifically [this image](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Mars/MarsScienceLaboratory/Mosaics/MSL_Gale_Orthophoto_Mosaic_10m_v3)) so I can add markers/lines/etc on it.

I know the min/max latitude/longitude for this image, so how would i go about turning this into a map i can zoom/pan/add markers/etc to?

I've used MapTiler but the free version has watermarks, the coordinates seem to be off and it's got the earth as it's basemap:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Openlayers 3 or 4, you can display an image as a base layer without depending on a WMS or a tile provider by using the `ol.layer.Image` constructor:

```
var imageLayer =  new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
              url: 'https://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Mars/MarsScienceLaboratory/Mosaics/thumbs/MSL_Gale_Orthophoto_Mosaic_10m_v3.jpg'
            })
          })
```

See this example from the Openlayers doc: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html?q=image

J.

Comment: For this example you linked the extent is the resolution of the image, what do i do if i want the extent to be [137.094719, -5.249559, 137.853827, -4.068583] so i can put in markers using mars coordinates? 

eg. add a marker at (137.4416334989196,-4.589466952134487)

Comment: You can specify your custom extent & projection for that image. But do you want to overlay with the OSM base maps as shown in your image?

Comment: I don't, just this image. I got it work defining a custom extent, thanks a lot for your help!